# android app - Did little changes in coding inside java and uploaded to play console, but still shows full size in playstore update

Tags: android, google-play, console-application

android app - Updated java class and uploaded (updated) to play console, but still shows full size in playstore update. i want it shows only updated size, not full size of app, because i just updated java file, not raw file which contains mp3.

Answer (score 0):

Google generates patches for difference dynamically (as they can be different for different users dependening on which version they already have. So if your app hasn't been downloaded that much, the patch might not be generated yet. Don't worry, as the updates get more popular, the patches get generated for the smaller update only delivery.